# entering variable interactively in a bash script with R system() function

Tags: r, bash

I have a bash script using the `read` function.
When calling it in Rstudio, that is doing `system("the script")` if I understood to documentation correctly, the script starts.

But when it ask me for input, I write and push enter, but the scripts does not go on, it did not interpret the enter as giving the answer.

Is there a trick to know, or is this just not possible ?

The minimal example, this is a .sh file open in RStudio, I push the run command:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "start: give answer "  
read commitmessage 

echo "answer read "
```

Comment: It's difficult to provide a solution without a minimal. Though, you can think about redefining your script to use external parameters which you then call via `Rscript`.

Comment: To expand on the "without a minimal" -- see [mre] guidelines. Exactly how your R program is started matters -- if there's no competition for the TTY, that makes things a lot easier -- but right now you haven't shown us enough to cause the same program ourselves with confidence that we're reproducing the details of the environment you need this to work in.

Comment: ...that said, it's certainly better practice to pass content from parent to child via the environment or argv rather than stdin where there's no particular reason to do otherwise.

Comment: The script is thought to be used via a double click on the desktop, I was hoping to be able to call it from Rstudio directly, instead of going to the folder and double-click it. Before tweaking the script so it can also accept the message as an argument, I wanted to check whether I missed something.